# Different versions of a library loaded to the same ClassLoader

Tags: java, class, classloader

Heyho,

Let's say we have this setup:

**Application** -> **plugin** -> **module**

Where "plugin" and "module" depend on "application".

*Application* uses the version 1.0 of a library. *Module* depends on the same library, but version 2.0. The classes are the same, but some methods are removed in 2.0 and a few added. *Plugin* uses the parent ClassLoader of *application* and *module* the parent ClassLoader of *plugin*.

Now the problem is that module uses version 1.0 of the library, but it depends on 2.0 -> *for example method not found*

What would be the propper way to fix this? Something that would work is to relocate the version 2.0, but maybe there is a workaround during runtime. Maybe it is possible to change the classloaders to fix the problem.

Max

Comment: You will have to fix your dependencies. There is no way to fix this. Consider you load a version of a `Class` from version 1.0 in Application and pass it to another `Class` in plugin, what happens then?

Comment: @BoristheSpider yeah except shading/relocating :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are:

1. upgrade the application to 2.0
2. downgrade the plugin to 1.0 (and hope it still works)
3. move the application "core" into a nested classloader
4. change the plugin/module classloaders so that they are not "parent first".  note that this is a very sketchy option which can really mess things up if not done correctly.

Option 3. would look like:

```
Application Base -> plugin -> module (lib 2.0)
                 -> Application Core (lib 1.0)
```

This essentially makes the plugin and the application core peers and therefore there is no longer a classloader issue.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean with your 3. option. As far as I can see module 1.0 and module 2.0 still use the classloader of the application base as parent.

Comment: And what do you mean with application base and core? Isn't this the same?

Comment: @p000ison - yes, but since the module is not available in the base classloader, it will be loaded by the child classloaders.  As for alpplication base and core, no, i am saying you need to split the application into two separate classloaders.  the base classloader has the "bootstrap classes" and any "api" class needed by the plugin.  the application core classloader has all the "implementation" classes which plugin/module don't need to use directly.  note that this doesn't affect how plugin/module are loaded, it just moves a lot of the application classes into a separate classloader.

Comment: I think this is not really possible in my case because I can not change the application base/core and how the plugin is loaded. Seems like relocating is the only solution

Comment: but what if the implementation already depends on the library? For example if the library provides an interface

Comment: @p000ison - i'm not following what you are saying.

Comment: my problem is that I can not change my application base, so the application base already contains all libraries, but I want to use a different version of a library in my plugin. So when my plugin enables the version 1.0 of the library is already loaded

Comment: @p000ison - i undestand what you _want_ to do, however that is not possible.  i've explained some options which _are_ possible.  i guess there is one other option, which i'll add to the answer.

Comment: thanks anyway, you can add as 5. option to relocate the classes of library 2.0 for example with maven. Seems like this is the only possible solution in my case